# How to read messages from topic using multiple subscribers at a time?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am working on Azure ServiceBus Topic-Subscriptions. I created one topic and two subscriptions in Service Bus Namespace. In my current application, I am able to send messages to topic after that I receive messages by using subscribers.

But whenever one subscriber will read messages from topic then the messages are gone into Dead-Letter-Queue. That’s why second subscriber will be unable to read messages from topic.

I wrote this line in my code after process message from Topic

```
await subscriptionClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
```

I followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues) for implementing above scenario.

So, can anyone suggest me how to read messages from topic using multiple subscribers at a time.

Answer (score 0):

> whenever one subscriber will read messages from topic then the messages are gone into Dead-Letter-Queue. That’s why second subscriber will be unable to read messages from topic.

Either there's a processing logic error and message is retried until it gets moved to the dead-letter queue or you've got `MaxDeliveryCount` set to one processing attempt. Either way, check `DeadLetterReason` and `DeadLetterErrorDescription` headers/properties for the reason message got moved into dead-letter queue.

> can anyone suggest me how to read messages from topic using multiple subscribers at a time.

Azure Service Bus supports [competing consumer pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/competing-consumers), you don't have to do anything special.

Comment: @Thanks Sean, I set `Max Delivery Count` as 1 to my subscriber. And I checked DeadLetterReason in the DLQ which contains the message as `MaxDeliveryCountExceeded`. For example, If  I have 3 subscribers in one Topic then I need to set 3 as `Max Delivery Count ` is it right?

Comment: Suggest to read up on the delivery mode [`PeekLock`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/peek-lock-message-non-destructive-read) and [competing consumers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/competing-consumers) pattern. Those are two different things that will help to understand how to use `MaxDeliveryCount` (accounting for failing processing, intermittent issues, etc) vs how brokered messages are consumed. If you want **each** subscriber to receive a message, you'll need to have a **subscription entity for each subscriber**. That's how pub/sub works.